# EquivalentC# coding for Dim dataTable As DataTable = CType(sender, GridView).DataSource

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

i am trying to convert Vb.net To C#.net. could any one please help me to find the Equivalent C# coding for Dim dataTable As DataTable = CType(sender, GridView).DataSource.
 and also,any tip for soring datas in data gridview.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?:

```
DataTable dataTable = ((GridView)sender).DataSource;
```

To cast types in C#, you put the type in parentheses before the value:

```
(GridView)sender
```

Then, to access properties on it, you'll want to wrap the whole thing in parentheses:

```
((GridView)sender).DataSource
```

(This is because otherwise you'd be trying to call `.DataSource` on the un-cast `sender` which would fail.)

Then to declare a value (the variable that you're assigning), the standard syntax is to specify the type and then the variable name:

```
DataTable dataTable
```

(I highly recommend using a better variable name, by the way.  C# is case-sensitive, so this is valid.  But it's unintuitive at best.)

In C# you can also use the `var` keyword to infer the type, often resulting in cleaner code:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
```

This only works if there's an inferrable type from the right side of the assignment.  Since the `DataSource` property isn't *specifically* of type `DataTable` then you don't want to use `var` in this particular case, since it would result in an `Object` (which isn't what you're looking for).  But it can be used in cases like my last example above this paragraph where you don't want to repeat the type name twice in the same line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dataTable = ((GridView)sender).DataSource
```

Regarding sorting in a GridView, see [Sorting Data in a GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875.aspx), then post a question with what you have tried if you're having problems.